# Extjs: cannot get view by xtype (Cannot convert undefined or null to object )

Tags: extjs

I have a simple window which wanna show it as a pop up. My question is how can I access this window from my controller with its xtype.

```
    Ext.define('My.view.definition.PropertyToDTWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    requires: ['My.view.definition.PropertyToDTForm'],
    alias : 'widget.PropertyToDTWindow',
                title: 'Add Property',
                closeAction: 'hide',
                width: 300,
                height: 350,
                layout: 'fit',
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                autoCreate: true,
                items: 'propertytodtform',
            });
```

What I need to do inside my controller is to call the window and show it like this but it doesn't work and I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object** error:

```
      var form = this.getPropertyToDTWindow();
      form.show();
```

Here is my xtype def:

```
    {
        ref: 'PropertyToDTWindow',
        selector: '',
        xtype: 'PropertyToDTWindow',
        autoCreate: true
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried repeating your xtype in the selector-property of the references? I suppose this does not work `selector: ''`

Comment: yes it was the problem. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selector` has to be something, as specified for [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).
`xtype` defines which component is created when using `autoCreate`. [Check the specs here.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
var win = Ext.create('My.view.definition.PropertyToDTWindow').show();

var form = win.down('#your-form-itemId').getForm();
```

If this doesn't work then you can directly access the field as below:

```
win.down('#firstname').setValue('Tim');

/*
 * #firstname -> textfield with itemId firstname
 */
```